# Submit form, do in-page processing, and submit again

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I have two PHP pages, A and B.

Page A has a form, which passes $_POST['mode'] variable with value 'edit' to page B.

Page B also has its form, whose submit button is named as '_go'. Page B checks if the $_POST['_go'] parameter is set and process the form within the same page B.

The problem is that, on Page B, if I input some value on the form and submit the form the first time, it works and I get the success message. However, after I get the success message, without refreshing the page, re-input another value and re-submit the form, I get nothing and the re-inputted value is not processed.

I looked into this myself, and found that $_POST['_mode'] is the cause of the problem. When I submit the form for the first time, $_POST['_mode'] is 'edit'. But when I re-submit the form, $_POST['_mode'] is still set but its value is empty.

I am frustrated here.

1. Page B gets $_POST['mode'] with value 'edit' from Page A
2. Page B stores $_POST['mode'] to variable $mode, and now the value of $mode is 'edit'
3. Page B submits the form, now $_POST['_mode'] is set and the value of $_POST['_mode'] is 'edit'.
4. Page B re-submits the form, since I didn't refresh the page or something, the value of $mode should still be 'edit' and I suppose the value of $_POST['_mode'] is also 'edit', but $_POST['_mode'] is set but EMPTY.

How do I keep $mode as it is?

My code in page A is like below (simplified).

```
// PAGE A

<form action="Page B" id="some id" name="some name" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edit" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

My code in page B is like below (simplified).

```
// PAGE B

<?php

  // if form is submitted and mode is 'edit', go process the form

  if( isset( $_POST['_go'] && isset( $_POST['_mode'] ) ) {

    $_go_mode = $_POST['_mode'];

    if( $_go_mode == 'edit' ) {
      process_form();
    }

  }

  function process_form() {

    // This function receives parameters from the form
    // and does what it needs to do

    echo '<div class="process-result">';
    echo 'Successfully made changes';
    echo '</div>';

  }

?>

<div>

  <?php

  // This $_POST['mode'] variable is passed from Page A

  if( isset( $_POST['mode'] ) ) {
    $mode = $_POST['mode'];
  }

  ?>

  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_name" value="some value" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="_mode" value="'.<?php echo $mode; ?>.'" />
      <input type="submit" name="_go" class="btn" value="Make Changes" />
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

As a work-around, I changed the code as below. Now it works as intended, but I don't feel this is a nice way to do it...

```
Before:
        if( $_go_mode == 'edit' ) {
          process_form();
        }

After:
        if( $_go_mode == 'edit' ) {
          $_POST['mode'] = $_go_mode;
          process_form();
        }
```

Comment: it will be empty the variables and post's get reset after page reloads

Comment: I need a bit more clarification. Even if I process the form within-the-same-page using if( isset( $_POST[ ] ) ), it is regarded as page reload and the variables are gone?

Comment: i posted a answer for you, to clarify when you load the page first time it will have $_post['mode'] loaded to page and you can get the variable and set it. when reloading the page the is no $_post['mode'] anymore because no post data was send to the page. best way i think is to use sessions thats why i changed your code to use sessions.

Comment: Thanks, Gert, for spending your time to provide me your valuable advice. Anyways, I forgot to mention that I am on Wordpress and initiating a manual session looks doubtful to me, tho.

Comment: i can post a code that i wrote for a answer for radio buttons without sessions but it is just 1 page posting to the same page if you want i can add that code to my answer maybe it is helpful

Comment: you can try it then leave a comment what doesn't work then  try give you some help , been writing php for years but now learning swift code just on here to keep my fresh in php lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have modified your code to use sessions it will solve the problem of loosing the variable and you can reuse it even in other pages. i have set the action of page a form to "" as i am creating the session in page A then redirecting to page b .note the "session_start();" must be on top of each page the only code above it can be "

page A

```
<?php
session_start();
   if( isset( $_POST['mode'] ) ) {
      $mode = $_POST['mode'];
      //setting a session
      $_session['mode']=$mode;
      //put your own file name for b in next line
      header("location:pageb.php");
      }
?

<form action="" id="some id" name="some name" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="edit" />
  <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

page B

```
<?php
session_start();
//checking for the session and assigning variable name 
if (isset($_session['mode'])) {
    $mode = $_session['mode'];
    }
// if form is submitted and mode is 'edit', go process the form
if( isset( $_POST['_go'] && isset( $_POST['_mode'] ) ) {
    $_go_mode = $_POST['_mode'];
    if( $_go_mode == 'edit' ) {
       process_form();
       }
  }

  function process_form() {

    // This function receives parameters from the form
    // and does what it needs to do

    echo '<div class="process-result">';
    echo 'Successfully made changes';
    echo '</div>';

  }

?>

<div>


  <form action "" method="post" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Some label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="_name" value="some value" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="hidden" name="_mode" value="<?php echo $mode; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" name="_go" class="btn" value="Make Changes" />
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

check this out  posting to same page

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="anyname" action="" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="asia"/>asia
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="africa"/>africa
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="my radio choice">
        </form>
<?php 


    function choose(){
        //declare it is a global variable from outside the function
        global $choice;


        if ($choice =='africa') {
        $test='you choose africa';
        }   
        elseif ($choice =='asia'){
        $test='you choose asia';
        }
        //returning the output of the function
        return $test;
        }



    //here you proccess the data after the page reloads

    if (!empty($_POST['choice'])){  
        $choice=$_POST["choice"];
        //running the function
        choose();
        //getting the output from the function
        $testafter=choose();
        echo 'this is the data after the page reloads :',$aftertest;
        }



    //here you process the data before the page reloads
    if ((isset($_POST["submit"])) && ($_POST["submit"]!="")){
        $choice=$_POST["choice"];
        //running the function
        choose();
        //getting the output from the function
        $testbefore=choose();

        }
?>


    <body>
</html>
```